# React set value to select not working but use selected in option is fine

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In my case, I use a select to maintain some search conditions like this:

```
<select onChange={this.props.onSelectChange}>
    <option value="" selected={this.props.searchTerms.condition== ""}>
       Select Option
    </option>
    <option value="opt1" label="opt1" selected={this.props.searchTerms.condition == "opt1"}>
       opt1
    </option>
    <option value="opt2" label="opt2" selected={this.props.searchTerms.condition == "opt2"}>
        opt2
    </option>
    <option value="opt3" label="opt3" selected={this.props.searchTerms.condition == "opt3"}>
        opt3
    </option>
</select>
```

You can see I'm using selected property in options to make the selected item is the value I set.

But in this way I will get warning from react said I should use value instead. After I change it like this:

```
<select onChange={this.props.onSelectChange} value={this.props.searchTerms.condition}>
   <option value="" }>
      Select Option
   </option>
   <option value="opt1" label="opt1" >
      opt1
   </option>
   <option value="opt2" label="opt2" >
      opt2
   </option>
   <option value="opt3" label="opt3">
      opt3
   </option>
</select>
```

The set value is not reflected to selected item. But the props is changed correctly, I print it some where and the value is right.

I used react-redux in this case, the prop is changed from a action dispatch from some button, in that action the search state will be updated and the search state is bind to prop by using redux.
Here is the redux related code:

Binding:

```
 export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
      onSelectChange: event => dispatch(updateSearchTermsAction("condition", event.target.value)),
      buttonClick: event => {//this is the issue event
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(updateSearchTermsAction("condition", "opt2"));
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Action:

```
export const updateSearchTermsAction = (key, value) => ({ type: UPDATE_SEACHTERMS, key: key, payload: value });
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = fromJS({ panelState: true, searchTerms: { condition: "" }, data: [] });
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SEACHTERMS:
      console.log(`${action.key} change detect ${action.payload}`);//correct here
      return state.setIn(["searchTerms", action.key], action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

And for debug purpose, I output the whole 'searchTerms' to HTML like that:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props.searchTerms, null, 2)}</pre>
```

After button clicked, the buttonClick is triggered, the action dispatched, from reducer I can see correct value in console, and the output in `Pre` is changed too, but the select does not change.

Please give me some advises about where might be the reason.

Comment: Post your `state` and `onSelectChange` function, and try to print `this.props.searchTerms.condition` before return and post the output.

Comment: @ravibagul91 please see my update, I posted the major redux related code.

Comment: Have you tried returning the dispatch function? It's the only thing different from the onSelectedChange ```return dispatch(updateSearchTermsAction("condition", "opt2"));```

Comment: honestly I really don't know what happened, the code just worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have not tested but you can try two methods for the same.

1. assign prop value into state and set it `value={this.state.value}` in the value attribute.

or

2. use sanitize for the value `value={sanitize(this.props.searchTerms.condition)}`

Comment: The state way is working. Then something strange happened, I undo the state change to origin version(assign prop to value), it's working now! I am absolute confirmed it's not working in morning! how could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the [relevant react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag), I was creating a minimized version of your select code, it works well for me

```
 const Component = () => {
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState("")
  return (
    <div>
      <select 
        value={condition}
        onChange={(evt) => setCondition(evt.target.value)} 
      >
        <option value="">
            Select Option
        </option>
        <option value="opt1" label="opt1" >
            opt1
        </option>
        <option value="opt2" label="opt2" >
            opt2
        </option>
        <option value="opt3" label="opt3">
            opt3
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jbugqv